# How can liferay template show page specific info

Tags: templates, liferay

I need to make some parts in template show or hide based on what page i'm on. I know I can make multiple themes in liferay-look-and-feel.xml file and give settings but this creates multiple themes in admin.

Is there some other way like accessing info about what portlets are on this page. Lets say if it has log in portlet then don't show navigation links for example?

Answer (score 1):

I think the simple way is to add this function over javascript. With javascript you can e.g. observe existing of login-portlet-id and then hide the navigation.

Answer (score 0):

In liferay template, a velocity variable is available called the $processor. It is nothing but object of

> com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.velocity.TemplateProcessor

The portletId is available in this object, but there is no direct method to get it. Please have a look at:

[TemplateProcessor.java.html](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/5.2/javadocs/portal-impl/com/liferay/portlet/layoutconfiguration/util/velocity/TemplateProcessor.java.html)

Once you get the portletId, then you can write the logic to hide certain sections.